# CSS selector: How to select button within div which is not direct parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-115eb3f58 one column_pricing_item servicebutton">
  <div class="pricing-box pricing-box-featured pricing-box-box">
    <div class="plan-header">
      <h2>Service</h2>
      <p class="subtitle">xyz</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan-inside">
      <h5>Our Service</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="plan-footer">
      <a
        href="#"
        class="button button_theme button_js"
        ><span class="button_label">More</span></a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I select the button with the label "More" for CSS by "referencing" the first div with the class `servicebutton`?

```css
.servicebutton > .button_theme {...}
```

does not work.

```css
.plan-footer > .button-theme {...}
```

does work, but I need to select by using the class `servicebutton` from the first `div` element.

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

Comment: Just remove the `>` - `.servicebutton  .button_label {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boom. Just follow the chain down to the element you're after.

```css
.servicebutton .plan-footer .button_label {
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-115eb3f58 one column_pricing_item servicebutton">
  <div class="pricing-box pricing-box-featured pricing-box-box">
    <div class="plan-header">
      <h2>Service</h2>
      <p class="subtitle">xyz</p>
    </div>
    <div class="plan-inside">
      <h5>Our Service</h5>
      <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="plan-footer">
      <a
        href="#"
        class="button button_theme button_js"
        ><span class="button_label">More</span></a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```